# Can't get Accuracy above 15% on CIFAR-10 dataset

Tags: classification, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using Convolutional Neural Networks to tackle image recognition. I used it for MNIST and got an accuracy of 99% but on trying it with CIFAR-10 dataset, I can't get it above 15%. It doesn't seem to learn at all.
I load data in dict, convert the labels to one-hot, then do the following below:

1.) Create a convolution layer with 3 input channels and 200 output channels, do max-pooling and then local response normalization

2.) Create a second convolution layer with 200 input channels and 500 output channels, do max-pooling and the normalization

3.) I use reLu activation except in the final layer which is sigmoid.

4.) I use softmax cross entropy cost function and Adam Optimizer.

```
def initializer(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x,W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x , W , [1,1,1,1] , padding="SAME")

def max_pool(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x , [1,2,2,1] , [1,2,2,1] , padding="SAME")

W_conv1 = initializer([2 , 2 , 3, 200])
b_conv1 = initializer([200])

W_conv2 = initializer([5 , 5 , 200 , 500])
b_conv2 = initializer([500])

W_fc1 = initializer([8*8*500 , 2048])
b_fc1 = initializer([2048])

W_out = initializer([2048 , 10])
b_out = initializer([10])

x_image = tf.reshape((x/255.0) , [-1,32,32,3])

h1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image , W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h1 = max_pool(h1)
h1 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(h1)

h2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h1 , W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h2 = max_pool(h2)
h2 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(h2)

h2 = tf.reshape(h2 , [-1,8*8*500])

h3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h2 , W_fc1) + b_fc1)

h3 = tf.nn.dropout(h3 , keep_prob)

h_out = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h3 , W_out) + b_out)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=h_out))

train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(h_out, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

This is the gist of my code.
Apart from that, I loaded the data and converted it into one-hot encoding using the below code:

import numpy as np
import cPickle

```
def unpickle(file):
    with open(file , 'rb') as fo:
        dict = cPickle.load(fo)
    return dict

def convert_one_hot(data,size):
    data_size = np.shape(data)
    final = np.zeros((data_size[0],size))
    final[np.arange(data_size[0]), data] = 1
    return final

def next_batch(dict,size):
    data_size = np.shape(dict["data"])
    label_size = np.shape(dict["labels"])
    final = (data_size[0] , (data_size[1] + label_size[1]))
    data = np.zeros(final)
    data[:,:data_size[1]] = dict["data"]
    data[:,data_size[1]:] = dict["labels"]
    np.random.shuffle(data)
    return data[:size,:data_size[1]], data[:size,data_size[1]:]
```

Can anyone help me get some accuracy on the dataset?
CIFAR-10 : https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html

Thank you.

Comment: I found out that the cost stagnates at the value of 2.261150. Why is that so?

Comment: Forget it, I found out. It was poor weight initialization that caused it!

Answer (score 0):

Woaa, hold on a second, I haven't ran the code myself, but already know why its not working: **you are just exploding the number of model parameters** without thinking what they do. So lets check what you are trying to do:

1. How many parameters do you have?
   Just the first FC layer: 8*8*500*2048 = 65 million parameters.
   The entire CIFAR-10 dataset is 153 million pixels. You can essentially store half of your dataset in parameters, this is a very bad ratio. Practically you fit one variable for every input, your model is not sufficiently overdetermined no wonder that you are brutally over-fitting. You either need more training data (augmentation) or drastically cut the number of parameters. Add more convolutional/pooling layers to reduce the image dimensions further, but here comes the next catch:
2. What does this convolutional layer do?

   ```
   W_conv1 = initializer([2 , 2 , 3, 200])
   ...
   h1 = max_pool(h1)
   ```

   You expect 200 basic combinations of 3x2x2 = 12 pixels. Realistic structures start around 3 pixels, but even then there are no 200 independent bases for a 3 channel input. Either go 256x5x5 kernels or 64x3x3 (the larger the kernel the more independent bases). The max pooling makes it even worse, essentially the first layer does nothing but resizing by local maximum interpolation with some smoothing. You need some overlap between your kernels, so take at least 3x3 kernels.
3. For such a small dataset, I find the number of low-level channels generally too high, the 200 and 500 channels for 3 and 7 pixel receptive field, or a 2048 channel FC layer right after a not-so-downsized convolution is a luxury for this dataset and will lead to over-fitting.

Comment: Okay, how about fitting the kernel at 3x3 and using this architecture:

Input -> 16 filters -> 2x2 max-pool -> 32 filters -> 2x2 max-pool -> 64 filters -> 2x2 max-pool -> 10 output layers

Comment: Thats a bit cutting it too much, but its going up nicely above 60%. Maybe add a not too big fc layer between the conv and softmax, or add further convolutional/pooling layers to get more nonlinearities. You could also try ELUs instead of RELU, they are easier to handle and more tolerant to preprocessing. But I think the exact network design is a matter of taste and fine tuning. Edit : 67%+ within 40 epochs.

Comment: I have heard CIFAR-10 is an easy dataset and I want to get at least near 90 on it. Currently am testing the following architecture:

16 -> 32 -> pool 3x3 -> 32 -> 64 -> pool 3x3 -> 64 -> 128 -> pool 2x2 -> Dense 256 -> Dense 10 output

Where only the 128 conv layer is with kernel 5x5, others are of kernel 3x3

Comment: CIFAR-10 is easy but small, getting over 80% generally requires data augmentation (ie. distorting, rotating or flipping the images to get "more" training data) or cherry picked hyper-parameters. Otherwise the architecture sounds good.

Comment: I have read a lot of papers that say their architecture gets 90% + without data augmentation. However I implemented a couple of them and got stuck around 75%, I don't know why.

Also, will it be possible to contact you through mail or something. ( I don't know if this is allowed here in this site, but I would really appreciate it if I could discuss with you some more and work to get above 80-90% )

Comment: I could also not reproduce them :) Also, some claimed models with ~40M parameters and 80% accuracy, which is "dubious" at least. Private messaging is discouraged on StackOverflow.

Comment: Maybe you could try this:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06037.pdf

I tried this on keras with horizontal flip allowed but could still only reach 75%